# pre hung doors to fit into old frame

Tags: installation

I have purchased some pre hung doors at 30" by 80"
the jambs are 4 5/8 wide. 
The house is 50 years old and the existing door frame is 5 1/4 wide.
Any solution as to how to fit these doors into the old frame.

Comment: are they split jam pre-hung doors?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is install the door with what is called a "jamb extension". Just get some strips of 5/8"x3/4" inch molding, then glue them to the non-hinge side of the new door jamb.  On a painted jamb these will for all intents and purposes disappear with sanding and some wood putty.  On a stained jamb you'll be able to see the extension, but you can minimize how much it stands out by picking wood with a similar grain pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Take off the trim, remove the old frame, install the new frame, re-install trim or install new trim. That, or re-use the existing frame by hanging the new door in it.